# Angular: when I press 'n' key, in the input field date, I want my day to move to the next day

Tags: angular, date

I am working on this project and need help to increase my day by one, when i insert 'n' key
here is what I've been doing and still don't have any change

```
addDays($event) {
    const date = new Date();
    if ($event.key === 'n') {
      // add a day
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
  }
```

the html:

```
<input matInput id="datePicker-{{rowIndex}}" [matDatepicker]="datePicker" [(ngModel)]="row.date" required maxlength="10" (change)="isOccurrenceDateValid(rowIndex)" 
            class="mat-input-element-style" **(keydown)="addDays($event, rowIndex)"**>
```

Comment: I am not sure if it has been pointed, but your first part of the code seems incorrect, you have a conflict with date there no ? you are just modifying the `const date` ? 

Can you share more code ?

Comment: the only conflict i have is pressing the n key and not receiving anything. i don't get it when you say modifying the const date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@koyes Here is a little example, I've made some tweak to the previous answer to meet what you need

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vcbpqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

```
<input
    matInput
    [ngModel]="date"
    [matDatepicker]="datePicker"
    required
    maxlength="10"
    class="mat-input-element-style"
    [readonly]="true"
    (keydown.n)="nextDay($event)"
  />
```

```
nextDay(event: any) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.date = new Date(this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1));
  }
```